# ReactiveCocoa: How do you bind a button's title to a text property?

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I've got a UIButton whose title for state normal/highlighted should keep synced with a property of its container object.

How can I bind button title for specific state with a string property?

**Edit**:

I know that using RACObserve and change the button title in subcribeNext block is a solution.
I'm looking for something more specifically designed for UIButton like:

```
RACBindButtonTitle(button, property, state1, state2);
```

I don't know if there is some "RAC sugar" like this.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such "sugar" in RAC, at least I couldn't find it in the docs: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.5/. If you want to use it in different places, you can create it quite easily.

Comment: @MichałCiuba I think I should start a new repository for it now :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean they're synced with one property, something like this:

```
[RACAble(self.buttonTitle) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newTitle) {
    NSString *normalTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Normal %@", newTitle];
    NSString *highlightedTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Highlighted %@", newTitle];
    [self.button setTitle:normalTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button setTitle:highlightedTitle forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}];
```

If you mean there're two properties, something like this:

```
[RACAble(self.normalButtonTitle) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newTitle) {
    [self.button setTitle:newTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}];

[RACAble(self.highlightedButtonTitle) subscribeNext:^(NSString *newTitle) {
    [self.button setTitle:newTitle forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}];
```

Comment: Thank you, Allen, using RACObserve is a common solution, I was looking for something more specify for such scenario(if there is), sorry for that I didn't clarify that in my question.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do it without explicit subscription.
Explicit subscription should be avoided whenever possible so that you don't have to go through the whole `@weakify(self)` `@strongify(self)` dance.

```
[self.button rac_liftSelector:@selector(setTitle:forState:)
                withSignals:
                            RACObserve(self, normalButtonTitle),
                            [RACSignal return:@(UIControlStateNormal)],
                            nil];
[self.button rac_liftSelector:@selector(setTitle:forState:)
                withSignals:
                            RACObserve(self, selectedButtonTitle),
                            [RACSignal return:@(UIControlStateSelected)],
                            nil];
```

`liftSelector:withSignals:` will subscribe eagerly to its signals, unlike many another RAC functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/xareelee/55c9a965212ebab524c8).

You can't use `RAC()` directly on a UIButton because of [the UIKit design](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1148):

```
RAC(self.button.titleLabel, text) = titleSignal;  // Don't do this.
```

One of the solutions is using dynamic property to support `RAC()` binding macro:

```
// .h
@interface UIButton (RACTitleSupport)
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *racExt_Title;
@end

// .m
@implementation UIButton (RACTitleSupport)
@dynamic racExt_Title;
- (void)setRacExt_Title:(NSString *)racExt_Title
{
  [self setTitle:racExt_Title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
- (NSString *)racExt_Title
{
  return [self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end
```

Now you can use `RAC()` binding macro like this:

```
RAC(self, button.racExt_Title) = titleSignal;
```

Cheers <3